# Adhesive strength of chewing gum

Tags: materials, automotive-engineering

What would the adhesive strength of chewing gum be? Would it be enough to support a car bumper? I'm more interested in how much tensile strength chewing gum has. I'm working on a project regarding the used cars movie, and in the movie, the salesman repaired a bumper that was unconnected with chewing gum.

The bumper I'm thinking of is the one featured in the beginning of the movie, a '57 Chevy sedan. I want to see if it is even plausible for chewing gum to support a car bumper, so assume a fixed load of just the bumper. Since it was the '50s I would guess the bumper would be 25 pounds at least.

Comment: Do you have any idea currently available advise material. I know in NASCAR other semi and professional Duck tape is used hold bumper or other loose fixture particularly after an accident

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short Answer

Yes it can hold. Because there are 10 brackets on a '57 Chevy front bumper and some more on rear bumper but not all of them are always under load conditions. A broken bracket or lost screw can be compensated with chewing gum.

## Long Answer

I haven't seen an actual '57 Chevy Sedan however with some chewing gum can hold bumper for a time if its used for lost screws on side brackets. Because of the design philosophy it seems there are a lot redundancy in bumper brackets. Modern bumpers are expected to break easily but in 50's they were sturdier.

### Front Bumper

Below is the assembly image I've found from [TriFive.com](http://www.trifive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=28049)
[image: '57 Chevy Sedan Front Bumper Assembly]

As you see the side bumper screws are under shear only under acceleration. So a chewing gum will hold it.

If brackets in the middle are loose some chewing gum can hold it for time again there are 10 brackets. But I'm not sure you can reach them without loosening sides.

### Rear Bumper

Rear bumper assembly is from TriFive.com again.
[image: Rear bumper '57 Chevy]

If bumper sagged because of a few screws got loose or bracket legs are broken chewing gum can hold for some time. However again it won't hold for long.